# Glassfish v3 blocks suddenly and runs out of max-threads

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-6

Can s.b. tell me what can cause this:

Server doesn't do anything anymore:

```
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadcount-count = 500
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadsbusy-count = 500
```

Lot's of th is in the log:

```
[#|2013-05-06T13:06:07.917+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-8083-(498)|#]
[#|2013-05-06T13:06:09.917+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-8083-(499)|#]
[#|2013-05-06T13:06:10.917+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.0.1|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=16;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Interrupting idle Thread: http-thread-pool-8083-(500)|#]
```

Normal behaviour:

```
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadcount-count = 427
server.network.http-listener-1.thread-pool.currentthreadsbusy-count = 8
server.network.http-listener-1.connection-queue.countqueued1minuteaverage-count = 184
server.network.http-listener-1.connection-queue.countqueued5minutesaverage-count = 3014
server.network.http-listener-1.connection-queue.countqueued15minutesaverage-count = 10058
```

Comment: are you closing connections properly?

Comment: Not sure. Can you give me an example. I use jaxrs for communication. And PHP as client query's the glassfish server. Do you means from client side, or server side?

Answer (score 0):

If you run out of connection this may indicate that your connections are not closed after they've been used. Hard to give an example without seeing your implementation of opening/closing the database connections. But normally you want to make sure that you close the connection in a finally clause, i'll provide an example below:

```
try {
   //Some logic that reads/writes to the database

}catch (SQLException e) { //Rollback in case something goes wrong
    try {
    System.out.println("Rolling back current db transaction");
    conn.rollback();
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        System.out.println(e1);
            }
}finally{ //Close the connection
    conn.close();
    System.out.println("DB connection is closed");
}
```

So that the database connection will be closed regardless if the reading/writing fails or not. If you fail to close these connections correctly these connections will remain open (or time out depending on your settings) and you will eventually run out of connections

Comment: Isn't it about http-thread-pool connections and not database connections? The database connections are handled from glassfish. I use JPA EclipseLink. And it's all containermanaged.

Comment: It's always time consuming to debug errors like this. The thread pool says how many request that can be processed simultaneously, as the connection pool says how many connections to keep in memory in order to speed up opening of new connections. When you get an error like this, it may be because you have opened connections that uses a thread in your thread pool and keeps in occupied, or it may be due to some other error that uses up your threads

Comment: Yes, needle in the haystack. :-(

Comment: Making sure that you do not have any infinite loops and that connections gets closed is a good place to start

Comment: Also, you can set the Timeout paramter so that threads will be released within the specified time

Comment: I changed from 900 sec. to 30 sec.

Comment: Having timeout set to 900 sec can indeed create the problem that you've described. Taken from the glassfish API: `. In practice, clients frequently connect to the server and then do not complete their requests. In these cases, the server waits a length of time specified by the Timeout parameter.`